# Union of two tables with different count in linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'd like to combine following two queries and get them into list. How to do it?

```
var query  = (from a in xactCtxt.XactETL_Activity_Log
                             join b in xactCtxt.XactETL_Shred_Mode on a.ShredModeID equals b.ShredModeID
                             where a.CreatedDate >= startDate && a.CreatedDate <= endDate
                             select new { a.ActivityLogID,a.ShredQueueCount,a.ShredCompletedCount,a.ShredValFailureCount,a.ShredExceptionCount, a.CreatedDate, b.ShredModeStatus })                                
                             .ToList();

                var historyCount = (from h in source.Histories
                                    where h.TransactionDate >= startDate && h.TransactionDate <= endDate
                                    select h).Count();
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest some solution?

Comment: What output you are expecting here ?